# Tool which checks that security best practices are in place

Tags: linux, security, debian, firewall, linux-networking

I want to secure my servers more, and so was wondering if there were any great tool to help me tighten the security on linux machines (or more specifically debian).

For exemple, this tool (or collection of tools, but I'd rather have something simple and to the point) would :

- raise a warning if `ssh` accepts password auth
- raise errors if outdated libraries and programs known to have big security holes are installed/used...
- if `apache`/`nginx`/whatever is installed, raise warnings and/or errors if the confs are not secure enough, or to advise installing this or that module for better security, ...
- raise errors if common programs can be accessed with the default user/pwd
- optionally : list programs which receive and send data, on which ports (handy to find rogue programs)
- optionally : give security best practice advice, depending on the software installed on the server.
- ...

Server security is a big subject, and without such a tool I think only the most experienced sysadmins can make a server really secure (and even them must forget some important conf change from time to time).

**Ideally, this tool would be run from the command line and display clear errors and warnings so that I could make the required changes and run the tool until everything is ok.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching your system package tree for `audit`. My Gentoo offers the following:

```
* app-admin/lsat
     Homepage:            http://usat.sourceforge.net/
     Description:         The Linux Security Auditing Tool

* app-forensics/lynis
     Homepage:            http://cisofy.com/lynis/
     Description:         Security and system auditing tool

* app-forensics/yasat
     Homepage:            http://yasat.sourceforge.net
     Description:         Security and system auditing tool
```

I recommend [lynis](http://cisofy.com/lynis/) to begin with.

Comment: This tool gives lots of infos and some nice recommandations, thanks :) I am still going through it... do you know if it gives out a list of open ports that should be closed too?

Comment: Lynis was a good start, and auditing tools in general should do what I was looking for :)